# Python subprocess32.py “OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory”

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, memory

I am running a python script which plots some outputs from a database, in Ubuntu 12.04, it usually runs perfectly but for large database I get the below error related to memory (The traceback is very long I just post the last rows). Is there anyway to solve this issue ?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 825, in __init__

restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1396, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)

OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: a) Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL. Update! b) You are running out of RAM.

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this issue ? Profile your code to see where the memory is being consumed. Then figure out how to use less memory by redesigning your code. Due to the lack of details your question is too broad.